# How to use two events on different elements for one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have two functions now that each start on a different event (`click` and `blur`) both start when interacting with different elements. Is there a way to combine the two? So when clicking the button, the function fires and when losing focus on an input (`blur`) the same function starts **without sending an ajax call twice**? So clicking an input should not start the function, only clicking the button.

These are my functions as they are now:

```
$("#account-details").on("click",".save-button",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // if($('#registerform')[0].reportValidity()){
        accountform = $(".account-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:"includes/updateaccount.php",
         data:({accountform: accountform}),
         success:function(data){
             var obj = JSON.parse(data);

             for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                 var status = obj[i].status;
                 var field = obj[i].field;
                 if(status == 'error'){
                     var message = obj[i].message;
                        $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).addClass('invalid-input');

                        var errorveld = $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' );
                        $( 'input[name="' + field + '"] + div').remove();
                        errorveld.after('<div class="inputerror">' + message + '</div>');
                 }else if(status == 'success'){
                     $( 'input[name="' + field + '"] + div').remove();
                     $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).removeClass('invalid-input');
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 // }else{
 //
 // }
});


$("#account-details").on("blur","input",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // if($('#registerform')[0].reportValidity()){
        accountform = $(".account-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:"includes/updateaccount.php",
         data:({accountform: accountform}),
         success:function(data){
             var obj = JSON.parse(data);

             for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                 var status = obj[i].status;
                 var field = obj[i].field;
                 if(status == 'error'){
                     var message = obj[i].message;
                        $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).addClass('invalid-input');

                        var errorveld = $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' );
                        $( 'input[name="' + field + '"] + div').remove();
                        errorveld.after('<div class="inputerror">' + message + '</div>');
                 }else if(status == 'success'){
                     $( 'input[name="' + field + '"] + div').remove();
                     $( 'input[name="' + field + '"]' ).removeClass('invalid-input');
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 // }else{
 //
 // }
});
```

I found another question with this answer:

```
$('#element1, #element2').on('click change', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (($this.is('#element1') && event.type === 'change') ||  ($this.is('#element2') && event.type === 'click')) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

The problem is my elements are children of a parent (`#account-details`). How can it be done?

Comment: What is `#account-details`? Because if it has `blur` and `input` it means that it's a form element. But `$("#account-details").on("click",".save-button"` means that it's a parent of `.save-button`..

Comment: @MoshFeu `#account-details` is the id of the form yes.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `form` has `input` event. Interesting. Regarding your question, I'm guessing your scenario is when user typed on the input, and then clicked on the `.save-button`, the `$.ajax` called twice, right?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes that is what is happening at the moment.

Comment: So you probably need sort of [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) mechanizm to not call the submit function is it called twice. My question is, if you save the form anyway on `input`, why you need the submit button anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer you found:

```
$('#account-details .save-button, #account-details input').on('click blur', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (($this.is('#account-details input') && event.type === 'blur') ||  ($this.is('#account-details .save-button') && event.type === 'click')) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

I hope this is the solution that you are looking for